# $viewContentLoaded is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have this function and when i click button nothing happend. I just get RESPONSE in console log but after that i dont get anything. Something is wrong with $viewContentLoaded.Any suggestion?

```
$scope.ConfirmTicketPayOut = function (ticketPin, username) {
            $scope.ticketPin = ticketPin;
            localStorage.setItem("ticketPin", ticketPin);
            accountDataProviderService.confirmTicketPayOut(ticketPin, username)
            .then(function (response) {

                $scope.confirmTicketPayOut = response;
                console.log("RESPONSE: ", $scope.confirmTicketPayOut);
                $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
                    console.log("VIEW CONTENT LOADED");
                    if ($scope.confirmTicketPayOut.Result == true) {
                        console.log("RETURN TRUE");


                        var w = $window.open('/account/ticketprint');
                        angular.element(w).bind('load', function () {
                            w.print();
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: I am wondering, why you even need `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {` there?

Comment: @YOU because im trying first to load partial view then option to print, but in my case first loads print option and then partial view if u know what i mean?

Comment: not very sure I understand, but how about trying to change that `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded'` to `$scope.$evalAsync(function (){ ... }) `or `$scope.$evalApply(function(){` ... or `$scope.$$postDigest(function(){ ...`?

Comment: @YOU on click i want to open partial view(ticketprint) in new window and call print for that partial view function but somehow when i click on button it opens me empty page with print function...do u understand me now?

Comment: My opinion is that partial view is render after print call but i dont know how to fix that

Comment: may be $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded' only works if you put right inside controller, not inside $scope.ConfirmTicketPayOut, but in your case you need $scope.$watch, not $viewContentLoaded i think. something like `$scope.$watch('confirmTicketPayOut.Result', function(newVal) { if (newValue === true) { ... });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82812/discussion-between-none-and-you).

Comment: I am not very sure how angularjs works in popup window. so not much idea here.

Comment: Hmm..i dont know either...but i need to do like that :)

Comment: @YOU do u have any suggestion ?

Comment: may be use modal popup like ngDialog, bootstrap $modal instead of window.open?

Comment: I would if i know how...because im not that good in programming :)

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact problem last night. Try using $watch instead of $on.

Comment: you mean   $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function () {...} ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I went with